# Core Data changedValuesForCurrentEvent EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8

I'm getting crash reports for my app that seem to be caused by Core Data somehow. Unfortunately I can't figure out what causes it and have no idea how to debug it. What would the best approach to find the error here be?

If it's relevant, I'm using RestKit 0.23

Here is an excerpt from the crash reports.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000482bbeb8

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019437bbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182a7d498 -[__NSCFNumber isEqual:] + 52
2  CoreData                       0x0000000182865e90 -[NSManagedObject changedValuesForCurrentEvent] + 380
3  CoreData                       0x00000001828651f4 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _preprocessUpdatedObjects:insertsInfo:deletesInfo:updatesInfo:sectionsWithDeletes:newSectionNames:treatAsRefreshes:] + 1248
4  CoreData                       0x000000018295a3b4 __77-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 1648
5  CoreData                       0x00000001828d9218 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 200
6  CoreData                       0x00000001828d90e4 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 256
7  CoreData                       0x0000000182864650 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 124
8  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b3a2c4 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
9  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182a77450 _CFXNotificationPost + 2060
10 Foundation                     0x00000001839a6a80 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 72
11 CoreData                       0x00000001828645ac -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 88
12 CoreData                       0x000000018286452c -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _createAndPostChangeNotification:withDeletions:withUpdates:withRefreshes:] + 364
13 CoreData                       0x00000001828629d4 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _processRecentChanges:] + 2552
14 CoreData                       0x000000018285adc4 _performRunLoopAction + 384
15 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b4c2a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
16 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b49230 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 360
17 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182b49610 __CFRunLoopRun + 836
18 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000182a752d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
19 GraphicsServices               0x000000018c2936fc GSEventRunModal + 168
20 UIKit                          0x000000018763afac UIApplicationMain + 1488
21 MyApp                          0x00000001001216b8 main (main.m:13)
22 libdyld.dylib                  0x00000001949e6a08 start + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

in line 10 you sent a notification. are you sure that the notification observer still exists? depends on the notifcation configuration but notis are not send immediatly. the error msg says that you wants to send a message `objc_msgSend` (or call a selector) to an invalid address `EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`, so there is no object.

Comment: I'm not sure it still exists, but I also don't send the notification myself. In line 11 there is _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo which I assume sends the notification?